# For a POST or PUT request, in my request payload if a mandatory parameter is missing then, what is the HTTP status code to be returned?

Tags: rest, http

My Request Payload for a POST or PUT request is as follows:

```
{
  "domainId": 1,
  "roleId": 1,
  "date": "2017-1-5",
  "downloadStatus": "true"
}
```

All the parameters in the above payload are mandatory. If one or more mandatory parameters are missing in the payload, then which HTTP Status code is to be returned?

Answer (score 2):

From the [W3C page related to Status Code Definitions](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.4):

> ### 10.4.1 400 Bad Request
>
> The request could not be understood by the server due to malformed
>   syntax. The client SHOULD NOT repeat the request without
>   modifications.